# Nestjsx/crud + typeorm + postgres - filter only when certain condition is met

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I use those filters on my user controller and they works just fine. But now the system needs to apply some of those filters only when the user is not an super user. how can i use the filter property to check if the user is a su? Here is the actual code:

```
@Crud({
    model: {
        type: User,
    },
    routes: {
        createOneBase: {
            returnShallow: true
        },
        updateOneBase: {
            returnShallow: true,
        },
        replaceOneBase: {
            returnShallow: true,
        },
        exclude: ['deleteOneBase', 'updateOneBase', 'createManyBase'],
    },
    params: {
        id: {
            field: 'id',
            type: 'number',
            primary: true,
        },
    },
    query: {
        join: {
            createdBy: { eager: true, exclude: ['password'] },
            updatedBy: { eager: true, exclude: ['password'] },
            members: { eager: true, alias: 'groups' },
            contacts: {eager: true, alias: 'contacts'},
            'members.group': { eager: true },
            userCompanies: { eager: true },
            'userCompanies.companyId': { eager: true }
        },
        filter: {
            exclude: {
                $eq: false,
            },
            'contacts.exclude': {
                $eq: false,
            },
            'userCompanies.exclude': {
                $eq: false,
            }
        },
        sort: [
            {
                field: 'id',
                order: 'ASC',
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

The only one which will be applied no matter the user type is the exclude one.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved by myself using the override method with ParsedRequest.

```
@Override('getManyBase')
async getMany(@ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest, @UserReq() user: User) {
    if(!user.su) {
        req.parsed.filter.push({
            field: 'contacts.exclude',
            operator: '$eq',
            value: false
        },
        {
            field: 'userCompanies.exclude',
            operator: '$eq',
            value: false
        })
    }

    return await this.service.getMany(req);
}
```